# Perl Strptime Error

Tags: perl, time, strptime

I am currently trying to parse data from a CSV file, which in the first column has time stamps that look like this:

07/26/2014 00:23:09

I read the documentation for Time::Piece which I already use to parse other types of timestamps, and it seems that the format string for this time style should be "%D %T". However, when I try the line

```
$temp_time = Time::Piece->strptime($fields[0], "%D %T");
```

Where $fields[0] is the string containing the timestamp, I get this type of warning when executing:

```
 garbage at end of string in strptime:  03:19:24 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 469, <$data> line 11933.
```

Any pointers? I've also tried "%m/%y/%d %H:%M:%S" and that does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second format string has the year in the middle spot.

Perhaps the following will help you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $str = '07/26/2014 03:19:24';

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");

print $t->strftime("%a, %d %b %Y"), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Sat, 26 Jul 2014
```

Comment: You're right, I still am not sure why "%D %T" doesn't work though. Thanks!

Comment: @JedTan `%D` requires a two-digit year, not a four-digit year as in `07/26/2014`.

Comment: According to [`strftime`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/), `%D` is equivalent to `%m/%d/%y`.  Note the lower case `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%D` format specifier is equivalent to `%m/%d/%y`, where `%y` (lowercase 'y') is the year *without the century* (i.e. 0-99). You're using a four-digit year, so that won't work.

Instead, use

```
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('07/26/2014 00:23:09', '%m/%d/%Y %T');
```

(note the uppercase `%Y`)

Run `man strptime` for more information about format specifiers, or see the [FreeBSD manpage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/) linked from the [`Time::Piece` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your initial way *with* the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime(
    "07/26/2014 00:23:09", 
    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
print $time;
```

Comment: You're off by six years: prints `Sun Jul 26 00:23:09 2020`